# How to pack all the dependencies of a netstandard2.0 project together into one package?

Tags: .net, nuget, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

I have a tool that supports plugin API - it loads the given assembly at runtime.

Now I am implementing a plugin for this tool. The target framework is .NET Standard 2.0. The plugin depends on two other NuGet packages.

I want to create a NuGet package with the plugin and all of its dependencies inside, because otherwise the tool will not be able to load it. But the bin\Debug\netstandard2 folder does not contain any of the dependencies.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me. This is what `dotnet publish` does.

Now I have to figure out the best way to pack it.

I ended up with the following script:

```
param($BuildNumber = $env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER, [switch]$NoPublish = $($env:BUILD_REASON -eq 'PullRequest'))

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

$Properties = @{
    BuildNumber = $BuildNumber
    SourceRevisionId = $(git rev-parse --short HEAD)
    RepositoryUrl = $(git remote get-url origin)
}
$BranchName = $env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME
if (!$BranchName)
{
    $BranchName = git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
}

$MSBuildProperties = $Properties.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object { 
    $_.Value
} | ForEach-Object { 
    "/p:{0}={1}" -f $_.Key,$_.Value 
}

Write-Host "Building ..."
dotnet publish -v:q -nologo -c Release $MSBuildProperties
if ($LastExitCode)
{
    exit $LastExitCode
}

Write-Host "Packing ..."
$MainAssemblyName = (Get-Item *.sln).BaseName
$MainAssemblyPath = "$PSScriptRoot\src\bin\Release\netstandard2\publish\$MainAssemblyName.dll"
$NuspecFile = $($MainAssemblyPath.Replace('.dll', '.nuspec'))
$VersionInfo = (Get-Item $MainAssemblyPath).VersionInfo
@"
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <metadata>
    <id>$MainAssemblyName</id>
    <version>$($VersionInfo.ProductVersion)</version>
    <authors>Mark Kharitonov</authors>
    <owners>$($VersionInfo.CompanyName)</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>$($VersionInfo.Comments)</description>
    <copyright>$($VersionInfo.LegalCopyright)</copyright>
    <projectUrl>$($Properties.RepositoryUrl)</projectUrl>
    <repository type="git"
                url="$($Properties.RepositoryUrl)"
                branch="$BranchName"
                commit="$($Properties.SourceRevisionId)" />
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="*.*" target="tools" />
  </files>
</package>
"@ | Out-File -Encoding utf8 $NuspecFile

Remove-Item src\bin\Release\*.nupkg -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
dotnet pack -v:q -nologo -c Release --no-build -p:NuspecFile=$NuspecFile
if ($LastExitCode)
{
    exit $LastExitCode
}

if (!$NoPublish)
{
    Write-Host "Publishing ..."
    $NuGetPkg = (Get-Item src\bin\Release\*.nupkg).FullName
    dotnet nuget -v Error push $NuGetPkg -s http://devstatic/NuGetServer/nuget
}
```

The source code has the following `Directory.Build.props`:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <NoWarn>NU5105</NoWarn>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>

    <Version>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match($(BuildNumber), `\d+\.\d+(?:.\d+)?(?:.\d+)?`))</Version>
    <Company>YabaDabaDoo, Inc.</Company>
    <CurrentYear>$([System.DateTime]::Now.Year)</CurrentYear>
    <CopyrightYears Condition="$(CurrentYear) == 2018">2018</CopyrightYears>
    <CopyrightYears Condition="$(CurrentYear) != 2018">2018-$(CurrentYear)</CopyrightYears>
    <Copyright>Copyright © $(CopyrightYears) by $(Company) All rights reserved.</Copyright>
    <Product>Log DbUpgrade Progress</Product>
    <AssemblyTitle>Log DbUpgrade Progress</AssemblyTitle>
    <Description>Logs the progress of the DbUpgrade tool to a file, which can later be used to send AppInsights metrics.</Description>
    <NeutralLanguage>en-US</NeutralLanguage>
    <Title>$(AssemblyTitle)</Title>
    <!-- Setting nuspec Owners property from msbuild is currently not supported. At the moment it is set to be equal Authors. -->
    <Authors>$(Company)</Authors>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

This is the simplest I have without duplicating any configuration.